# Changing div content, with other div contents

Tags: javascript, html

I've probably been browsing the wrong search words while trying to look for the answer to this problem, but all I find are jQuery solutions.

What I'm trying to achieve is by the click of different buttons, is to change the content of a "container" div, with the corresponding div content that you click the button for.

I feel like my javascript in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PjVL6/4/) is not sufficient, but it's all I could come up with from my browsing.

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<div id="work1" class="work">Content 1</div>
<div id="work2" class="work">Content 2</div>    
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="changeContent('work1');" value="work 1"/>
<input type="button" onclick="changeContent('work2');" value="work 2"/>
```

CSS

```
#content{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Javascript

```
function changeContent(){
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = document.getElementByClassName('work');
}
```

I'm using classes because I thought it would cut down on the javascript needed?

Comment: You are setting the innerHTML to a node list...what are you actually trying to do? Show/hide content?

Comment: Switching between them. I guess you could say show and hide. Like such: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/BcFVv/ but in javascript, not jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function changeContent(id){
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('work');  //get elements with the class
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {  //loop through them all
       elems[i].style.display = "none";  //set display to none to hide them
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";  //find the element passed in and show it
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementByClassName('work');
```

Supposed to be

```
document.getElementsByClassName('work'); // check the missing s
```

And this **returns a live node list**. If the ClassName for each is unique then you may directly use the first element

```
document.getElementByClassName('work')[0].innerHTML;
```

Also it is better idea to **bind events in javascript** rather than assigning the inline event attribute.

Answer (score 0):

if what i understand is correct, you are trying to show/hide content based on a click on a specific button

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#content{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

</style>
<script language = "javascript">

function showContent(value)
{
    if(value == 'work1'){
        document.getElementById('work2').style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById('work1').style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('work2').style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById('work1').style.visibility = "hidden";       
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="work1" class="work">Content 1</div>
<div id="work2" class="work">Content 2</div>    
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="showContent('work1');" value="show work 1"/>
<input type="button" onclick="showContent('work2');" value="show work 2"/>
</body>
</html>
```